# How to serve two web apps under single domain using nginx using different endpoints?

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2

```
server { # Listen on port 80 # Listen on port 80 for ipv6

    server_name www.mydomain.com;

    location /inventory/ {
        root /opt/mydomain/inventory/inventory-frontend/dist/;
        try_files $uri /index.html;
    }

    location / {
        rewrite ^/$ /inventory/ permanent;
        root /opt/mydomain/frontend-build/build;
        try_files $uri /index.html;
     }

    location /api/ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3030;
    }

    location /inventory/api/ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:6091;
    }

}
server {
    if ($host = www.mydomain.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot



    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name www.mydomain.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

I have two different apps one is user facing and another one is internal to me. I have only one domain as stated above and I want to serve two different web apps based on the endpoint. For example if someone visits [www.mydomain.com/inventory](http://www.mydomain.com/inventory) then it takes me to inventory app which is on different location as shown above and if someone visits [www.mydomain.com](http://www.mydomain.com) they get the user app. How to achieve this and not have conflicts? I can access both apps individually by putting it on root location but not after I serve it after an endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered deploying an AWS API Gateway?

Comment: I can't use it since I don't have the budget for now. Thanks for enlightening on this.

Comment: Are you sure an nginx deployed on EC2 is cheaper than https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/pricing/